# Several sendReponse in if statements not functioning due to error in indexOf

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, I have the following background.js as my background script which calls for the tab url and then determine if its secure.

#### background.js

```
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
      console.log('loaded');
    });
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function () {
      chrome.tabs.query({ 'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true }, function (tabs) {
        var url = tabs[0].url;

        console.log(url);
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
          function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
            if (url.indexOf('https') >= 0) {
              console.log('secure site');
              console.log(url.indexOf('https'));
              sendResponse({ security: "YES" });
            }
            else if (url.indexOf('https') < 0) {
              console.log('insecure site');
              sendResponse({ security: "NO" });
              console.log(url.indexOf('https'));
            }
            else {
              console.log('unable');
              sendResponse({ security: "?" });
            }
          }
        )
      })
    });
```

I have a message request from my popup.js (below) which sends a message to the background.js. There is a listener for the message and sends a response of YES of NO depending on if https is present.

#### popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ greeting: "hello" }, function (response) {
    if (response.security == "YES") {
        document.getElementById('webSecure').innerHTML = "YES";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('webSecure').innerHTML = "NO";
    }
    //document.getElementById('webSecure').innerHTML = response.security;
});
```

Then, the popup.js would get the element in my popup.html (below) and display the result.

#### popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="material.css">
    <script defer src="material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <style>
        body {
            width: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img src="logo_default256.png" id="logo" alt="logo-default">
        <div class="options">
            <label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-2">
                <input type="checkbox" id="switch-2" class="mdl-switch__input">
                <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
            </label>
            <a href="settings.html">SETTINGS</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <hr>
    <section>
        <div class="content">
            <h4>Is this website secure?</h4>
            <p id="webSecure" class="result">0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h4>Trusted Site</h4>
            <!-- Accent-colored flat button -->
            <p class="result">NO</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h4>Harmful Language</h4>
            <p class="result">0</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, this does not function properly. On install, it functions properly and displays YES for the https website. However, on the second attempt, I navigated to a http site and still got the output of YES. It seems that the response does not change from the first attempt.

When checking the console, the correct `site secure` response appears on the first attempt. On the second attempt, both `site secure` and `insecure site` appear but the former appearing first. This most likely is why YES appeared instead of No. When navigating to a http website on the first attempt, same thing occurs with it giving the right response but wrong response when navigating to https website on the second attempt.

This console picture shows the url being given and the response provided. Notice how the first response was correct but the second time, both responses were present which does not make sense.
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X50SM.png)

It seems that the if statements in background.js is remembering the previous result or something similar. I'm not familiar with the complete situation and would love to hear how I can resolve this.

Comment: In addition to what the answer below says, you don't need a background page for this because the popup has access to the same API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a message listener everytime a tab is updated, that's why there are several responses. Try this:

**background.js**

```
var url;
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
    console.log('loaded');
});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ 'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true }, function (tabs) {
        url = tabs[0].url;
        console.log(url);

        if (url.indexOf('https') >= 0) {
            console.log('secure site');
            console.log(url.indexOf('https'));
            sendResponse({ security: "YES" });
        }
        else if (url.indexOf('https') < 0) {
            console.log('insecure site');
            sendResponse({ security: "NO" });
            console.log(url.indexOf('https'));
        }
        else {
            console.log('unable');
            sendResponse({ security: "?" });
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

Comment: So the issue was that the process was repeated everytime a message was sent. And also it had to be performed synchronously?